# Putting "Align at equals" into a macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm working on a Word Macro to streamline doing my University Mathematics and Statistics Coursework. Basically, selecting a group of equations and running it changes font size, line height and formats the paragraph in the way that I want to be common to all my maths/equations sections. It's great, but there's one little bit which I still have to do "manually", so to speak, which is right clicking and selecting "Align at equals".

Now the reason I'm asking this here and not on Super User is that I think I've exhausted all ways of doing this at the "record macro" stage. I found out how to access the right click menu without right clicking and accessed the "align at equals" option during record. Nothing was recorded.

Truth be told I'd prefer to code the lot anyway as it gives me more control. So, I'll post my code here and if anyone knows what line(s) of code I need to add to get it to replicate the "align at equals" command I would be extremely grateful.

```
Sub Equationiser()
'

' Equationiser Macro

'

'
    With Selection.ParagraphFormat
        .SpaceBefore = 12
        .SpaceAfter = 12
        .LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpace1pt5
    End With
    Selection.Font.Size = 20
End Sub
```

So, ideally just before the "With Selection.ParagraphFormat" section there would be some kind of "AlignAtEquals" command or whatever is needed so that, on one keypress, I would be able to align all the equals, set the line height to 1.5, place a 12 point space before and after the paragraph and change the font size to 20.

My absolute ideal would also be to programatically select all equation boxes that are in the same block, as "align at equals" is notoriously fussy and finicky as to when it will execute. That might also mean there may be a try and catch needed depending on whether trying to run "align at equals" when it wouldn't normally be available from the right click menu would do nothing or cause an error.

Any help on these two implementations  would be gratefully appreciated but I'd happily settle for just the first.

Comment: I recently made use of spare time due to Covid 19 to revise my Ph D thesis (a pure text file from 1987) to current word format.  The simplest way I found for aligning equations was to use a three column table. e.g for x= a + b. a would be in column 1, = in column 2 and a+b in column 3.

Comment: Your equation formatting would be simpler if you created a style for it with the required spacings and font size. Applying it would then be as simple as Selection.Style = "Name of Style".

Comment: Although I see your point the macro idea has 3 significant upsides:
1. Now that I've had help from @Prebsus I can align all the equals signs which, I believe, isn't accessible via the stylesheet
2. I can bind the macro to a keypress.
3. I can write a larger macro, based on the revised Equationiser macro which could go through the entire document and format JUST the maths in tthe way I want it. 

So although your idea is an elegant workaround I think I'll stick to using a Macro.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that the style would replace the macro, simply the last 6 lines which handle the formatting. If your selection includes more than just the equations you could use .OMaths(equationCounter).Range.Style = "Style Name" within the main loop, which would also keep your code nice and tidy. Word is built around the use of styles, they are not optional, so it makes sense to use them. Styles make consistent formatting so much easier. Suppose you later needed to change the font size of your equations. Which would you rather do - reformat each equation or edit a single style?

Comment: The main reason I put the styling into a macro in the first place is that I don't trust the way Microsoft implements styles. I've had a setting for Title in one document where Word has refused to include the text size despite the fact that it's included in the style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've built a solution that should address your needs, based on:

1. Looking through the equation to find the `equal`-sign.
2. Get the location of that `equal`-sign
3. Use that location to set the AlignPoint property of the OMath object
   that is your equation

[Use this MSDN reference if you want to explore more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.omath)

```
Sub Equationiser()
'

' Equationiser Macro

'

'

    Dim equationCounter As Long, charLoc As Long, FormattedTextLoc As Long

    With Selection
        For equationCounter = 1 To .OMaths.Count:
            FormattedTextLoc = 0
            For charLoc = 1 To Len(.OMaths(equationCounter).Range.FormattedText):
                FormattedTextLoc = FormattedTextLoc + Len(.OMaths(equationCounter).Range.FormattedText.Characters(charLoc))
                If .OMaths(equationCounter).Range.FormattedText.Characters(charLoc) = "=" Then
                    .OMaths(equationCounter).AlignPoint = (FormattedTextLoc - 1)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next charLoc
        Next equationCounter
    End With


    With Selection.ParagraphFormat
        .SpaceBefore = 12
        .SpaceAfter = 12
        .LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpace1pt5
    End With
    Selection.Font.Size = 20
End Sub
```

I've done some brief testing that from what I can see this should be able to manage several code-blocks, *i.e.* when selecting 2 code-blocks it will align-at-equals all equations in the first block, then align-at-equals all equations in the second block (both blocks are not aligned with each oter) - **is this your desired outcome to your request:** *My absolute ideal would also be to programatically select all equation boxes that are in the same block, as "align at equals" is notoriously fussy and finicky as to when it will execute.*

Comment: Wow. 

I'll check it works but, yeah looks like it will do what I want. It has the added bonus that I can cannibalise it to play with and learn more about tinkering with The Maths Object in Word, which will be fun.

Thanks for such a quick reply and (hopefully) elegant solution. I'm marking it as the accepted answer as I can't forsee any problems if you've checked it and even if it needs a tinker you would have done most of the work needed anyway.

Comment: Glad to hear it! A warning (something that caused me a bit of problem) - When looking for the `equals`-sign in the Maths Object, I found that my initial approach failed. I tried to look at _e.g._ OMaths(1).Range.Characters and find the character location of `=`. However, the character location given there does not correspond to `AlignPoint` value, as most non-symbol characters (`a`, `x`, etc.) seem to be represented by `??` in FormattedText (hence have length of 2), while `=`, `+`, etc. have length of 1. This means a + b = c should have `AlignPoint=5`, and not `4`...

Comment: Will have to put a try and catch into this as there's sometimes an error - align at equals is notoriously finicky at when it chooses to turn up. and when an error occurs it doesn't do all of the formatting.

Comment: Always a good idea - or perhaps use the error handler with custom error handling.

Comment: Also going to do some work to expand it a bit - for instance the original alingn doesn't take into account things like "is not equal to", "is approximate to" "is greater"/"less than" and so on. It also always aligns the first equals in a group of more than one equal so there could be a way to handle that differently although putting too many equals signs on the same line is often bad mathematical communication so I might leave that bit be.

Comment: Glad to hear you're expanding on it. I agree that expanding on the `If .OMaths(equationCounter).Range.FormattedText.Characters(charLoc) = "=" Then` line by adding several conditions (not equals to, greater than, etc.).
Funny enough, I seem to remember thinking about the "what if there are several equal-signs in the same line", but decided that auto-selecting the first one is as good as any, as you point out: this could often be bad communication (several equals signs on the same line)

Comment: Yeah. Occasionally it can be useful and correct, like when I was explaining similarity between triangles of different sizes using the ratio rule
a/A = b/B = c/C
but, as multiple equals are usually used for short proofs like this or for checking the results of equation simplifications there's generally not that many equals signs used.